# Conditional Join SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, inner-join

I want to be able to inner join two tables based on the value of a column I'm selecting.

My Query:

```
SELECT varA, varB, MAX(varC) varC
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2       ON varB = table2.varB
INNER JOIN @tempTable   ON varA = table1.column
INNER JOIN table3       ON varC = table3.column AND table3.column2 = 1 -- **IF NOT varA = 100**
INNER JOIN table4       ON varC = table4.column  **-- IF varA = 100**
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5  ON table2.column = table5.column AND table5.column2 = 1 AND table5.column3 = 4
GROUP BY varB, varA
```

**So, in short INNER JOIN on table4 if value of column(varA) is not 100 else INNER JOIN on table3**

Comment: you have so many tables in the query not just **"two"**...so how does your table schema look like? ;)

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here, e.g. what does `OpvarB` refer to? Can you prefix the columns with their tablenames? Otherwise it is a lot of unnecessary guesswork on our part.

Comment: @DeanOC: simplified and updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will get the result you're after:

```
LEFT JOIN table3       ON varC = table3.column AND table3.column2 = 1 AND varA <> 100 -- **IF NOT varA = 100**
LEFT JOIN table4       ON varC = table4.column  AND varA = 100   **-- IF varA = 100**
...
WHERE (Table3.Column IS NOT NULL OR Table4.Column IS NOT NULL)
```

Basically allows a join to either table, but only return rows where one of those joins found a record. If you want to return the actual columns from the table as part of the select then you could use an ISNULL:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Table3.Column, Table4.Column) AS Column
```

---

EDIT: I should have added that you can't conditionally join to tables unless you want to use dynamic SQL. You can either join to the table or not. What I outlined above lets you do the join to both tables and then check that one of them did join (which is basically what an Inner Join does).

Comment: Yes, I tried this. Always returns rows much greater than what both of the selects return using inner joins, if run separately.

Comment: Did you include the extra AND clause in the join? I've done it this way a number of times and haven't had a problem before. Can you provide some data showing when it doesn't work?

Comment: The WHERE clause did it :)

Comment: Be careful with left joins used in this way as although not used they *may* multiple your results if it is not 1 to 1.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here @GeorgeMavritsakis. Inner joins would multiply your results in the same way wouldn't they?

Comment: Yes they would. I just wanted to clarify that when we do this (which is perfectly right) we must be carefull with multiple results as someone who don't pay attention, my think that the join won't happen as long as the first check is true. As you know, the join will happen and if the right side table has multiple matches for the left hand condition then, even if the first expression of the where clause would be true, the rows would multiply by the number of the rows matched on the right side table.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't quite clear and if this doesn't work please provide more info but I think this is your answer.

You can place a CASE statement in the join.

**Updated, try this.**

```
INNER JOIN table4 ON (CASE WHEN varA != 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND tablekey=table4key
INNER JOIN table3 ON (CASE WHEN varA = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND tablekey=table3key
```

Comment: I just updated the question.. how else can I make it more clear?

Comment: I don't think this will work. If varA = 100 then your join on table 4 will be where 1 = 0 which is obviously always false. Because you're doing an inner join it will filter out that record.

Comment: Ah yes I missed that, fixed.

Comment: @Preston I think you might have a typo still with the case statement on join to table3. Maybe I'm missing something though but I still don't see how this will work. If there is a record in table 3 only when varA = 100 and a record in table 4 when varA != 100 then you can't inner join to both. One of those inner joins will be null which will exclude that row from the results. I think they need to be left joins with some sort of check in the where clause to make sure one of them worked

Comment: I think it would work this way, VarA is a column in table1 according to the question. Allow me to do some testing and get back to this.

Comment: it does work as you can see here, I guess you could also just join it twice and do AND table1.varA = 100 that's far easier.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9da3a/2

Comment: Your example isn't quite right @Preston. You are only joining to table2, not to table2 OR table3

Answer (score 1):

> So, in short INNER JOIN on table3 if varA is not 100 else INNER JOIN on table4.

That cannot be effectively done in one query.  At execution time, the database must decide what joins to perform on a whole-table basis, not a row-by-row basis.  If you attempt to do what you propose, what you will get, at best, is that the database will join on both `table3` and `table4`.  At worst, the joins will be Cartesian (unrestricted "all rows * all rows" joins).

So you only have these two options:

1. Join to both tables, and select on a row-by-row basis whether to produce data from `table3` or `table4` for that row.
2. Split the query into two queries joined by `UNION`.  One of the queries joins with `table3`, the other joins with `table4`.  You use the condition to control which rows are produced by the first query and which by the second one; i.e., the subquery that joins with `table3` has `varA != 100` in the WHERE clause, and the subquery that joins with `table4` has `varA = 100`.